# How to make vertical custom view slider like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, slider, android-custom-view

I want to make **slider** with **custom view** and *length of views are not fix*.

Is it possible to make this?

**Attach Screen design** which I want to make. please see this to get a better idea of view and how it looks.

Please let me know if anyone has the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

[image: Layout design Screen to show how it looks.]

Comment: are your referring to bottom sheets?

Comment: You can check StackView for this animation .Just google StackView Android Example. Let me know if it solves your problem .

Comment: you can also check this link https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager .